# Get number of employees who worked in more than one department with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out a query which show the **number** (amount) of employees who worked in more than 1 departments. Here the table name and fields:

- `Employee`(id_employee, employee_name, salary)
- `Department`(id_dept, dept_name, budget)
- `Department_Employee`(id_employee, id_dept, workhours_percentage)

Suppose the content of Department_Employee table is

```
id_employee  id_dept  workhours_percentage
-----------  -------  --------------------
0001           03         100
0001           04          50
0001           05          60
0002           05          60
0002           09          90
0003           08          80
0004           07          80
0005           06          60
0006           05          70
0007           04          75
0008           10          95
0009           02          25
0010           01          40
```

With a right query, the result should be 2 (employees), because there are 2 employees who work in more than one department

- Employee 0001 work in 3 departments
- Employee 0002 work in 2 departments

I tried with the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_employee)
FROM Department_Employee
GROUP BY id_employee
HAVING COUNT(id_employee)>1
```

But the result isn't right.

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: When you group by `id_imployee` what do you think `COUNT(DISTINCT id_employee)` could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
SELECT id_employee, COUNT(*) AS CNT
FROM Department_Employee
GROUP BY id_employee
) AS T
WHERE CNT > 1
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But, would you mind if I asking for some explanation? :D

Comment: Department_Employee links the relation between employee and department. "Count(*)" will count the number of rows group by employee_id. "CNT" will be materialized in subquery and can be use as filter in "where" clause in the outer query.

Answer (score 3):

To get all employees that work in more than one department:

```
SELECT id_employee, COUNT(*)
FROM Department_Employee
GROUP BY id_employee
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

To count them:

```
;
WITH cte As
(
    SELECT id_employee
    FROM Department_Employee
    GROUP BY id_employee
    HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cte
```

Comment: I got error like this "No column name was specified for column 2 of 'cte'."

Comment: @KleinrockHyper Sorry, fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, now it works.
I have a further question, how to put that code into a function?

Comment: @KleinrockHyper What kind of function?  How would you be using it?

Comment: The function that could count the numbers of employees who work in more than 1 department. I tried to make query like following code:

(
    CREATE FUNCTION Func_EmployeesNumbers
    RETURNS NUMERIC
    AS BEGIN
    DECLARE empnumb NUMERIC
    SELECT empnumb = .......
    RETURN empnumb
    END
) [empnumb is the parameter/return value]
How to put your code in the SELECT part?

Comment: @KleinrockHyper This should probably be its own question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.id_employee, count(e.id_dep) from Department_Employee e group by e.id_employee having count(e.id_dep)>1 ;
```

In this I am trying to first trying to get a count of dept id group by id_employee 
and as our requirement is to find the employee who belongs to more than one department using having  count(e.id_dep)>1  to retrieve the same.

Comment: single-line solution should be in comment.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
  SELECT id_employee, COUNT(*) AS CNT
  FROM Department_Employee
  GROUP BY id_employee
) AS T
WHERE CNT > 1
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE  (SELECT count(dept) as empcount ) > 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**