# How to find employees who and worked in specific departments

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I select the employees who have worked in both departments 03 and 04. In this snippet only emp 0001 and 0004 have worked in both 03 and 04 dept.

```
id_employee  id_dept  workhours_percentage
-----------  -------  --------------------
0001           03         100
0001           04          50
0001           05          60
0002           05          60
0002           09          90
0002           08          80
0003           07          80
0003           06          60
0003           05          70
0004           03          75
0004           04          95
0004           02          25
```

Comment: Spookily similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608325/get-number-of-employees-who-worked-in-more-than-one-department-with-sql-query apart from selecting departments,

Comment: Yeah, I already checked the question, but Data is similar query is different.

Comment: Look again - with a few trivial tweaks the accepted answer will work for you.

Comment: @Prem, Try my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id_employee 
FROM Your_Table
WHERE id_dept IN('03','04')
GROUP BY id_employee
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id_dept)=2
```

**Output:**

```
id_employee
0001
0004
```

Comment: Great, I didnt understand the logic, but it's working thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GROUP_CONCAT` function along with `GROUP BY` to achieve this:

```
SELECT EMP_ID,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT DEPT ORDER BY DEPT ASC SEPARATOR '; ') DEPTS
FROM 
(
  SELECT '0001' EMP_ID, '03' DEPT, '100' WORK_PER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0001' EMP_ID, '04' DEPT, '50' WORK_PER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0001' EMP_ID, '05' DEPT, '60' WORK_PER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0002' EMP_ID, '05' DEPT, '60' WORK_PER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0002' EMP_ID, '09' DEPT, '90' WORK_PER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0002' EMP_ID, '08' DEPT, '80' WORK_PER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0003' EMP_ID, '07' DEPT, '80' WORK_PER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0003' EMP_ID, '06' DEPT, '60' WORK_PER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0003' EMP_ID, '05' DEPT, '70' WORK_PER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0004' EMP_ID, '03' DEPT, '75' WORK_PER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0004' EMP_ID, '04' DEPT, '95' WORK_PER FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '0004' EMP_ID, '02' DEPT, '25' WORK_PER FROM DUAL
) EMP
GROUP BY EMP_ID
HAVING DEPTS LIKE '%03; 04%';
```

It is similar to Oracle's `LISTAGG` function which aggregates the said column values in mentioned order with a separator which in this case is `'; '`. We are aggregating `DEPT` column and Grouping it using the `EMP_ID` and finally checking if the aggregated column has both of the required departments separated by `'; '`.

Hope this helps and explains. :)